# Create <select> elements on the fly and send multiple POST as an array using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, select, dynamic

I wonder if it's possible to populate `<select>` elements with option values generated by `PHP`to a page (after load) whenever a user is clicking a button with`id='add'`and then be able to store each value selected as an `array` then send this via `$_POST` to a `PHP` page?

I would like to populate the `<select>` element like this:

**/theloader.php**

```
echo "<select class='plan_id'>\n";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($course_elements)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['plan_id']."'>".$row['plan_name']."</option>\n";
    }

echo "</select>\n";

?>
```

This will output

```
<select class='plan_id'>
    <option value='1'>Description</option>
    <option value='2'>Description</option>
    <option value='3'>Description</option>  
</select>
```

Then when the user has populated the needed elements and selected values, click save and send everything to `anotherfile.php`:

```
$("#save").click(function() {

 // Store each value as a variable then send to /anotherfile.php

});
```

I lack knowledge in how to perform this kind of action and would really appriciate som tips in the right direction.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to use AJAX to update the content with PHP in the backend, right?

Comment: Meet [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason the population of the selects has to be dynamic? Does the data change, or are you just letting the user add more line items to choose from pre-set options?

If the data in the dropdown itself is dynamic, you will need a combination of javascript and ajax calls to get the data from the php in real time.

If the options are not dynamic, then you do not need ajax at all, just populate the variables in javascript and create an action to add more dropdowns using the already defined variables.

Comment: Yes it needs to be dynamic because tha data is changing.

Comment: Ok. Then you will want to use the AJAX functions built into jQuery. I think this page is the best place to start. It is not necessarily complex, but you'll really need to study it yourself to integrate it properly. As an overview, you'll need to use javascript to detect change on your form to signal this ajax call to get data from an external php file, then use the javascript to update the DOM with the returned data, without refreshing the page.